# How to get selected rows in lightning:datatable using onClick from lightning:button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-components

Use case: Users are presented with a datatable that they can select records from and click a button to convert those records into pdf

I can't get past the selecting and displaying the records in console. When I click the Generate PDF button, nothing happens. This is my code:

COMPONENT:

```
<aura:component controller='OppQRCont'
            implements='force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction'
            access='global'>
<aura:attribute type='Quote_Request__c[]' name='qrList'/>
<aura:attribute type='List' name='qrColumns'/>

<aura:handler name='init' value='{!this}' action='{!c.fetchQuoteRequests}'/>

<lightning:card title='Quote Requests' iconName='standard:lead_list'>
    
    <lightning:datatable aura:id='qrTable'
                         data='{!v.qrList}'
                         columns='{!v.qrColumns}'
                         keyField='id'
                         hideCheckboxColumn='false'
                         hideTableHeader='false'/>
    <aura:set attribute='footer'>
        <lightning:button variant='brand-outline' label='Generate PDF' title='Generate PDF Action' onClick='{!c.getSelectedQRs}'/>
        <lightning:button variant='brand' label='Generate PDF and send to email' title='Send to Email Action'/>
    </aura:set> 
</lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
({
fetchQuoteRequests:function(component,event,helper){
    helper.getQuoteRequestList(component,event,helper);
},
getSelectedQRs:function(component,event,helper){
    let lines = [];
    lines = component.find('qrTable').getSelectedRows();
    System.debug(JSON.stringify(lines));
}
})
```

HELPER:

```
({
getQuoteRequestList : function(component,event,helper) {
    component.set('v.qrColumns', [
        {label: 'Underwriter', fieldName: 'linkUnderwriter', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'Insurer__c', target: '_blank'}}},
        {label: 'Quote Amount', fieldName: 'Quote_Amount__c', type: 'currency'},
        {label: 'Class of Insurance', fieldName: 'Class_of_Insurance2__c', type: 'text'},
    ]);
    var action = component.get('c.oppQuoteRequestList');  
    action.setParams({  
        "recordId":component.get('v.recordId')  
    });      
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){  
        var state = response.getState();  
        if(state=='SUCCESS'){  
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            result.forEach(function(record) {
                record.linkUnderwriter = '/'+record.Underwriter__c;
            });
            component.set("v.qrList",result);  
        }  
    });  
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

APEX CONTROLLER:

```
public class OppQRCont {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Quote_Request__c> oppQuoteRequestList(String recordId){
    List<Quote_Request__c> oppList = [Select Id, Underwriter__c, Insurer__c, Quote_Amount__c, Class_of_Insurance2__c From Quote_Request__c Where Opportunity__c=:recordId and Quote_Amount__c != null];
    system.debug('oppList ' + oppList);
    return oppList;
}}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.